# unable to select layer for a given polygon input in arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy

I have created python script tool and able to select layer by providing feature classes as below.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/project/pmms.gdb"

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('stops', 'intersect', 'adminarea')
```

---

But when I used the following code to take user input polygon (`FeatureSet`), it fails and an error message is given. I have created a parameter of `FeatureSet` type to allow user to provide interactive polygon input. Please provide your suggestions.

```
import arcpy

fc = "C:/project/pmms.gdb/stops"

infeat = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fc, 'intersect', infeat)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\project\scripts\select.py", line 7, in <module>
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fc, 'intersect', infeat)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6585, in SelectLayerByLocation
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000368: Invalid input data.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).
```

Comment: formatted code and error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ArcGIS [help page on the Select Layer By Location function](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//001700000072000000):

> The input must be a feature layer; it cannot be a feature class.

Include a [Make Feature Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Make_Feature_Layer/00170000006p000000/) operation before attempting to select, and it should work as expected.

```
fc = "C:/project/pmms.gdb/stops"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, 'stops')
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('stops', 'intersect', infeat)
```

Just make sure you don't already have a layer in your ArcMap table of contents that is called `stops` (which is presumably why the previous version of your code was working correctly).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that, it works fine now. Can i assign the output from MakeFeatureLayer_management to some variable and use it ? or do i need to use SaveLayerFile_management ?

Comment: Throw a `lyrName = 'stops'` in there and then you can use `lyrName` (or whatever variable you want) instead of a string :)